# Some currency Symbol in Jasper report is not coming

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have created a jasper report template using jaspersoft studio and I am populating the template using java code. I have some data in the report which needs to be localize and for that I am seeting the "locale" by below code in java.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("zh", "CN");
templateParameters.put("REPORT_LOCALE", locale); //A map to pass to report
```

I have also tried -

```
Locale locale = java.util.Locale.CHINA;
```

In populated report "Number formatting" is there but currecny symbol is missing(only dollar, pound, euro symbols are coming)
Below is the code I have used in jasper report to populate the text field -

```
NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance($P{REPORT_LOCALE}).format($P{Param_Name})
```

I would be very thankful if someone could pointout the mistake or provide some suggestion.

Comment: Did you check expression like `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("zh", "CN")).format($P{Param_Name})`?

Comment: @AlexK, I tried after your comment but no luck. One interesting point is the symbol is coming in chart objects(because of jfree chart) but not in jasper native objects like textfields, grid etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your issue related with font supporting.

We should use *[Font Extensions](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/fonts/index.html#fontextensions)* in case using *JRPdfExporter*.

I tried to use font with *Chinese* support and in this case everything is OK.<sup>I don't know why using a ton of another fonts is not helping</sup>

### Example

#### Java code

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, Locale.CHINA);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, new JREmptyDataSource());
```

#### Report template

There are 4 *textField*s in *jrxml* file: two using font with *Chinese* support and another 2 - without it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Show currency" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="value" class="java.lang.Double" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[1234.567]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <title>
        <band height="70">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="10" width="300" height="15"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Sharp Dawn"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("zh", "CN")).format($P{value})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="25" width="300" height="15"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font fontName="Sharp Dawn"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance($P{REPORT_LOCALE}).format($P{value})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="3" y="40" width="300" height="15"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance($P{REPORT_LOCALE}).format($P{value})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="3" y="55" width="300" height="15"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("zh", "CN")).format($P{value})]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </title>
</jasperReport>
```

#### Output result

The *pdf* file generated with help of *JRPdfExporter* looks like

[image]

The *Yuan* symbol is showing only for first group.